# Записываю файл в кодировке utf-8, а читается он в cp1251, Java

Tags: java, кодировка

По задумке файл должен читаться в кодировке utf-8, а он читается нормально только в cp1251.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("read.html");
    byte[] str = new byte[inFile.available()];      
    inFile.read(str);
    String text = new String(str, "windows-1251");
    byte[] b = text.getBytes("utf-8");
    String t = new String(b, "utf-8");
    File file = new File("write.html");
    try {
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());   
        try {
            out.print(t);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `new PrintWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), "utf-8")`?

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло